# How to get hastable value in javascript from request?

Tags: javascript, java

I will pass hashtable in java to javascript but donot know how to get the value and assign to a variable in javascript

My code as follows, but getting undefined while parsing the hashtable

```
var hash={};
hash="${hashFromJava}";
console.log(hash);
console.log(hash[12]);
```

My Hash has value

```
{hash=value,hash1=value1}
```

Comment: Use a JSON converter

Comment: Object.keys(obj)

Comment: what is this Object.keys(obj) do ? @sForSujit

Comment: what is this Object.keys(obj) do ?and what is keys? is it a keyword? then what is obj? @sForSujit

Comment: Just show how did  you send hashtable in java to JS

Comment: `hash="${hashFromJava}";` is just a string, it's not a hashtable of any kind

Comment: in request i set hashtable object

Answer (score 0):

you should test the **object** with `JSON.stringify` first

e.g:

```
var object = {a: 1, b: 2};
console.log(JSON.stringify(object)); //=> {"a":1,"b":2}
```

and string you will retrieve from Java should be `"{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}"`

then for your case you need to use `JSON.parse`

```
var hashFromJava = "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}";
var hash={};
hash = JSON.parse(hashFromJava);
console.log(hash); // => Object {a: 1, b: 2}
```